# Index issues in python lists

Tags: python, list, indexing

```
for i in list:
    j = i + 1
    print i - j
```

This will print out -1 times the length of `list`

What I wanted to do is to print the difference between value i and the next in the list.

Am I clear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for i in list:
```

binds `i` to the elements of `list`, not its indexes. You might have meant

```
for i in xrange(len(list)):
```

or

```
for i, _ in enumerate(list):
```

Then get the element at index `i` with `list[i]`.

(And please don't call a list `list`; that's the name of a Python built-in function.)

Answer (score 4):

Unlike JavaScript, iterating over a sequence in Python yields elements, not indexes.

```
for i, j in zip(L, L[1:]):
  print j - i
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for i in xrange(1, len(lst)):
    print lst[i-1] - lst[i]
```

Notice that in the line `for i in list`, `i` is an *element* of `list`, not an index. In the above code, `i` is indeed an index. Also, it's a bad idea calling a variable `list` (Python uses that name for something else). I renamed it to `lst`.

Comment: for i in xrange(1, len(lst)):
    print lst[i-1] - lst[i]
That is exactly how I used larsmans answer.